# angularjs - filter value between 2 number

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i want to ask. I'd already search about angularjs filter but havent found yet what is the solution for mine. I use angular for make android app with IONIC framework.

I have data with price. I want to filter it by price range.

ex:

```
name      type        price
item01    fruit       25000
item02    vegetable   50000
item03    vegetable   10000
```

I have 2 select box for filtering

```
<select ng-value="fprice">
   <option value="">All</option>
   <option value="0">0-24999</option>
   <option value="25000">25000-49999</option>
</select>

<select ng-value="ftype">
   <option value="">All</option>
   <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
   <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
</select>
```

I want if i select the second value (price) then item02 didnt show.

I have code like

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { type: ftype, price: ??? }">
    {{item.name}}<br>
    {{item.type}}<br>
    {{item.price}}
    </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
```

What is the code for my `???` in my code? I have try some but still dont find what I looking for.

Thank you. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom filter. I post example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasmin_kurtic/5bL5tfo5/7/)

In filter you can put what you want.

my custom filter

```
autoDrops.filter('filterCostum', function () {
    return function (datas, fprice, ftype) {
            console.log(ftype)

        var options = [];
        angular.forEach(datas, function (data) {
                if(ftype != ""){
                if (data.type == ftype) {
                 if(fprice == ""){
                                     options.push(data);

                    }
                    else if(fprice == 0){
                            if(data.price >= 0 && data.price <=24999)
                            options.push(data);
                    }
                    else if(fprice == 25000){
                        if(data.price >= 25000 && data.price<=49999)
                      options.push(data);
                    }
                    }
            }
            else{
            console.log(fprice)
             if(fprice == ""){
                                     options.push(data);

                    }
                    else if(fprice == 0){
                            if(data.price >= 0 && data.price <=24999)
                            options.push(data);
                    }
                    else if(fprice == 25000){
                        if(data.price >= 25000 && data.price<=49999)
                      options.push(data);
                    }
                    }

            });

        return options;
    }
})
```

I call like this

```
<div ng-app="autoDrops" ng-controller="DropsController">
<select ng-model="fprice">
   <option value="">All</option>
   <option value="0">0-24999</option>
   <option value="25000">25000-49999</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="ftype">
   <option value="">All</option>
   <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
   <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
</select>
 <div>
     <div>
        <div ng-repeat="elem in datas | filterCostum: fprice: ftype">
        {{elem}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
```

link edited